# Using .split with tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, operating-system

Quite a beginner here. I have a command line script that works fine for what I do and I'm looking to move it into a GUI.

```
os.chdir(ImageDirST)

for f in sorted(os.listdir(ImageDirST)):
    f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
    f_sku = (f_name.split(' ')[0])
    f_num = (f_name[-2:])

    n_name = ('{}_{}{}'.format(f_sku,f_num,f_ext))
    print(f, "-->", n_name)
```

I would like this to display in the same fashion within a message window in tkinter.

With some help from here, I managed to print the filenames in the directory when a button is pushed with:

```
filenames = sorted(os.listdir(ImageDirBT))
text = "\n".join(filenames)
print_filename_test.set(text)
```

I have tried to use my split code to setup a list of what the new filenames would look like, prior to setting the variable, with the following, where print_filenames() is the function triggered by the press of a button.

```
def print_filenames():
filenames = sorted(os.listdir(ImageDirBT))
for filenames in sorted(os.listdir(ImageDirBT)):
    f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(filenames))
    f_sku = (f_name.split('_')[0])
    f_num = (f_name[-2:])
    n_name = ('{}_{}{}'.format(f_sku,f_num,f_ext))
newlist = "\n".join(n_name)
print_filename_test.set(newlist)
```

I don't get any errors with this code for print_filenames(), however what is displayed in the message panel is the last filename in the list, vertically, one character wide:
eg:

```
F
I
L
E
_
1
1
.
e
x
t
```

I would like to display the output as:

```
oldfilename_01.ext --> newfilename_csvdata_01.ext
oldfilename_02.ext --> newfilename_csvdata_02.ext
oldfilename_03.ext --> newfilename_csvdata_03.ext
oldfilename_04.ext --> newfilename_csvdata_04.ext
```

The command line program I have written uses numbers to chose menu options for what needs to be done, confirming before any renaming is done, hence printing the file name comparisons. My struggle is manipulating the strings in the list to be able to do the same thing.

Comment: which widget are you using to display the output? `Text`?

Comment: @Henry the message widget, however ideally it would be scrollable so I would be happy to change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `messagebox`:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

ImageDirST = r"your_path"
os.chdir(ImageDirST)

root = tk.Tk()

names = []
for f in sorted(os.listdir(ImageDirST)):
    f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
    f_sku = (f_name.split(' ')[0])
    f_num = (f_name[-2:])
    n_name = ('{}_{}{}'.format(f_sku,f_num,f_ext))
    names.append(f"{f} --> {n_name}\n")

messagebox.showinfo(title="Something", message="".join(names))
root.mainloop()
```

Or using `Text` widget with scrollbar:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
ImageDirST = r"your_path"
os.chdir(ImageDirST)

root = tk.Tk()
txt = ScrolledText(root, font="Arial 8")
txt.pack()

for f in sorted(os.listdir(ImageDirST)):
    f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
    f_sku = (f_name.split(' ')[0])
    f_num = (f_name[-2:])
    n_name = ('{}_{}{}'.format(f_sku,f_num,f_ext))
    txt.insert("end",f"{f} --> {n_name}\n")

root.mainloop()
```